# AWS ApiGateway Documentation support to Open Api 3.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

im asking here because i couldnt find any news about this topic.
does AWS going to support OpenApi 3.1 definitions for ApiGateway Documentation?

It seems strange to me that AWS doesn't have it since it was released three years ago

I designed an api with swaggerhub and OpenApi 3.1, i would like to import it to api gateway but as far as i know i have to convert that hudge file to a previous version.

Analyzing the diferences between OpenApi 3.0 vs OpenApi 3.1, i like more OpenApi 3.1 but there isnt any specific thing that holds me to migrate OpenApi 3.1 to 3.0... i just dont like downgrade versions

there is any workaround to import an OpenApi 3.1 definition?